# Como zerar o contador de mortes ,após iniciar uma nova partida PYGAME PYthon

Tags: python, contador

```
 def draw_game():
            tela.fill(BLACK)
            tela.blit(background, (0, 0))
            # Draw Player
            player.draw(tela)
            # Draw Bullets
            for bullet in player.bullets:
                bullet.draw_bullet()
            # Draw Enemies
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.draw(tela)
            # Player Health
            if player.alive == False:
                tela.fill((0, 0, 0))
                font = pygame.font.Font('fonte/PressStart2P-vaV7.ttf', 32)
                text = font.render('GAME OVER! pressione R', True, (138, 47, 47))
                textRect = text.get_rect()
                textRect.center = (metadeLargura, metadeAltura)
                tela.blit(text, textRect)
                if userInput[pygame.K_r]:
                    player.alive = True
                    player.lives = 1
                    player.health = 40





            font = pygame.font.Font('fonte/PressStart2P-vaV7.ttf', 27)
            text = font.render('Mortos: ' + str(kills) + '  Vidas: ' + str(player.lives), True, (189, 178, 209))
            tela.blit(text, (230, 20))

            pygame.display.update()
            CLOCK.tick(FPS)

        player = Hero(250, 410)
        enemies = []
        kills = 0

        while player.lives == 0:
            kills = 0
```

Eu estou tendo problemas na hora que acaba as vidas do personagem e dá gameover, pois quero que resete o contador de mortes a 0 quando dá Game over , mas já usei :

```
 while player.lives == 0:
                kills = 0
ou

 while player.lives < 0:
                kills = 0
```

e nada do contador de Mortes resetar. Gostaria de saber como resetar o contador de mortes ?

Comment: `while` vai prender o programa num laço de repetição. Tentou usar um `if`?

Answer (score 0):

Podemos zerar após o GAME OVER, mesmo sem lógica:

```
    if player.alive == False: # GAME OVER
            tela.fill((0, 0, 0))
            font = pygame.font.Font('fonte/PressStart2P-vaV7.ttf', 32)
            text = font.render('GAME OVER! pressione R', True, (138, 47, 47))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (metadeLargura, metadeAltura)
            tela.blit(text, textRect)
            if userInput[pygame.K_r]:
                player.alive = True
                player.lives = 1
                player.health = 40
                kills = 0 # Reinicia as mortes para uma nova jogada
```

Mas fazendo assim, lembre-se de apagar a variável no final do seu código, será inútil já que o jogador perdeu.

Ou podemos fazer como se o jogador tivesse 3 vidas, e dessa vez fosse a última:

```
    kills = 2
    if player.lives == 0:
        kills = 0
```

Comment: mas dá o erro quando eu insiro dentro do if userinput [pygame.K_r]:    text = font.render('Mortos: ' + str(kills) + '  Vidas: ' + str(player.lives), True, (63, 255, 223))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'kills' referenced before assignment  e mantenho as linhas de código logo abaixo  font = pygame.font.Font('fonte/PressStart2P-vaV7.ttf', 27)
                text = font.render('Mortos: ' + str(kills) + '  Vidas: ' + str(player.lives), True, (63, 255, 223))

Comment: que eu não posso declarar a variável Kills antes no código, de mostrar na tela o contador de kills

Comment: olha ai por favor #Carlysson Gabriel

Comment: Não me lembro desta lógica, mas acredito que faltava eu ver a parte de como era feita a subtração de vida do usuário @CaioGSaSilva